# What will be xpath query to read the value of tag element whose name attribute value is 'manufacturer'

Tags: xml, xpath

This is the sample XML file and I have to query the `tag` with the `name` attribute value 'manufacturer'.

```
<Car>
  <tag name="Engine">v12</tag>
  <tag name="Gear">6</tag>
  <tag name="SelfDrive">true</tag>
  <tag name="manufacturer">tesla</tag>
</Car>
```

Comment: You should try something rather than asking for the solution

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
/Car/tag[@name='manufacturer']
```

Explanation:

- `/Car` will select the tag `Car` from the root node
- `/tag` will select from the previous node, `Car` in this case
- `[@name='manufacturer']` will select only the elements that have an attribute `name` with a value of `manufacturer`